# Executing binary from grass shell?

Tags: grass-gis

I am using hydrologic modeling software, and it include a grass program that I need to run from the grass shell.

How do I get the grass shell to recognize/run the program?

The program is in the folder "/home/rowan/RHESSys/bin". I have tried to modify the .grassrc6 file, but that does not seem to work.

In the grass shell, the results of g.gisenv:

```
GISDBASE=/media/sf_C_DRIVE/lassen/grassdata
LOCATION_NAME=lassen_national_forest
MAPSET=PERMANENT
PATH=/usr/lib/grass64/bin:/usr/lib/grass64/scripts:/home/rowan/.grass6/addons:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/rowan/RHESSys/bin:/home/rowan/RHESSys/g2w/grass2world
MONITOR=cairo7
GRASS_GUI=wxpython
```

Even so, when I type the name of the program "g2w" the grass shell cannot find it, even though it is in the PATH variable.

What am I doing wrong?

The output of ls -la /home/rowan/RHESSys/bin is:

```
total 3872
drwxr-xr-x 2 rowan rowan    4096 Aug 11 12:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 rowan rowan    4096 Aug  7 14:39 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rowan rowan  186476 Aug 11 12:02 cf10.0b2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rowan rowan   37219 Aug  7 14:52 g2w
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rowan rowan   83094 Aug 11 12:29 lairead
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rowan rowan   32292 Aug 11 11:54 rat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rowan rowan 3607040 Aug  7 14:50 rhessys5.18
```

My .bashrc file has:

```
export 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/rowan/modflow2005/Unix/src:/home/rowan/RHESSys/bin'
export 'GISBASE=/usr/lib/grass64'
```

Comment: please add the output of "ls -la /home/rowan/RHESSys/bin" to your posting. In general it is better to add the path to $PATH (e.g. in your .bashrc file if you use bash) rather than editing .grassrc6.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the requested output and I have included the .bashrc export for my path variable.

Comment: Of course you restarted your GRASS session? And with "grass shell" you mean the shell terminal in which GRASS is running?

Comment: Yes, in the shell terminal grass is running and I did restart the grass session

Comment: Can you run successfully (with full path): /home/rowan/RHESSys/bin/g2w ?

Comment: When I run /home/rowan/RHESSys/bin/g2wI get: Couldn't open template file. Which what I would expect (it needs a template file to run). Also if I just type g2w it works as well. The problem is the file needs to executed from the grass terminal...

Comment: Maybe 32bit/64bit collision? Honestly, I have no idea (but also no Windows...)